# Write to S3 parquet with Impala

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, impala

I would like to write an entire table to s3a in parquet format. 
Let's call the table abc_schem.thattable. I would like to use an Impala query to 
SELECT * WHERE to_date(create_time) = 'YYYY-MM-DD'

What is the exact syntax for this to write to Parquet S3?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an external table in a specific location and insert into it assuming s3 system is already configured

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE abc_schem.thattable(
... 
) 
STORED AS PARQUET 
LOCATION 's3a://bucket/path';
```

Then use some `LOAD DATA` or `INSERT INTO... SELECT... FROM` commands to get data there

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE schema.temp_c 
STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION "s3a://s3highlevel/c/lowlevel" AS 
SELECT * FROM schema.table
```